# .NET Framework in Wine

Tags: virtualbox, .net-framework, sony-vegas

I need .NET Framework 3 (Sony Vegas Pro needs it) but I can't install it cause Wine errors. I have a Virtualbox VM with .NET 3 on it, I copied all the files in the Wine C: drive, and imported the reg key for .NET, but the program still asks me to install it.

What should I do?

Comment: You need Mono .net apps, not Wine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can install .net3.0 in wine ,instructions [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=9828) ,alternatively you can try opensource alternative of .net called [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

> Mono is a free and open source project led by Xamarin (formerly by
>   Novell and originally by Ximian) to create an Ecma standard compliant
>   .NET Framework-compatible set of tools including, among others, a C#
>   compiler and a Common Language Runtime.

Comment: Tried that guide, didn't work. Thanks for Mono, anyway